# [__NSCFBoolean length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10bd05c00

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime-error

Just working on an assignment in which i have to print data from the server into my table. written all code but, when I run my app the data is not printed in the table. During run time when I scroll the the table then it shows me this error. And the reason why data is not visible as per my investigation the compiler first go to table code then it move to connection code. that's the reason why the data is not being displayed(* I used breakpoints *).

thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us your code ;)

Comment: Show the code where the code is failing

Comment: cell.codeCell.text = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];cell.dateCell.text = [arrayDateData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.titleCell.text = [array4 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];  @QuentinHayot

Comment: This has nothing to do with either Xcode or syntax errors.

Comment: than how could i solve my problem? @TheParamagneticCroissant

Comment: Don't allow `length` to be called on things that don't have a length method.  That would solve your problem.  Without knowing the line that crashes, it's hard to say anything more specific than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setText like this :-

```
cell.codeCell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:%@,[array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

That will not crash your app.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `length method` on `NSNumber` object.
Without you showing us the code, there's nothing more I can do.
I expect you get data from server without checking it's type you assign it to textfield or something like that.

Best way to find it will be to make sure that the data is the type you expect it to be by breakpoint and calling `po [variable class]` in console.

If you are assigning it to textField, you should call `[variable stringValue]` and assign that to textField.

If you have BOOL value there, you need to do generate a string based on that value.

Comment: Thank you. Will check if in case i did any thing wrong.